# Custom X-axis label formatting in Winform Chart Control

Tags: winforms, charts, microsoft-chart-controls

I am plotting graph with numeric value on Y axis and Date time value on X axis in windows forms chart control. I am setting X axis scale "IsLogarithmic" to true and i am getting the graph as shown in the image ...[image]

I want to set the label formatting of X axis in such a way that it shows me 10^1, 10^2, 10^3 and so on...

Any idea or help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you consider using exponential notation like 10E+2 instead of 10^2?

Comment: I did, but requirement is 10^2...